Shortcut to pull up all file explorer windows that are open
Hi I'm trying to make a script to open all minimized file explorer windows at the same time. the gpt script I'm using below doesn't work.
$shell = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application
$shell.Windows() | ForEach-Object {
    if ($_.Name -eq 'File Explorer') {
        $_.Visible = $true
        $_.Document.Focus()
    }
}

I saved the file as text.ps1 and I am running it by creating a shortcut that will have a macro assigned to it. in the location field of the shortcut i have this location:
powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "C:\Desktop\text.ps1"

are there changes i need to make to the script, or is what i'm describing not possible to do? thank you!

How did you come up with .Focus() ? There is no method in .Document with that name

You should share any errors and details about what does or doesn’t happen. Honestly, It appears the code likely was generated by chatgpt or similar.

yes, the script was generated. there may be errors but I can't see them because the powershell window closes fast. it runs in a flash and closes the window. i'm trying to run this on a work computer, so maybe there are guardrails on it preventing this type of automation. I would still like to know how I can make this work on my personal comp

Are you trying to "restore" all minimized explorer windows?

yes but I want to restore all of them at the same time. I read I can do Shift+Right_Click on the explorer icon in the taskbar then "Restore all windows" but this is greyed out for me. I'd like to make a macro instead.
i have 6 folders open and arranged in a specific order while I work. as I use other applications, the file explorer windows get sent to the back or sometimes minimized to make room on my screen.
instead of pulling up one explorer window at a time, I want all 6 back up in one macro

I highly doubt this Shell.Application implementation will do it for you. If you want to restore windows properly the best is to use native functions with c# implementation. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-enumwindows and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendmessage

thanks for the replies! i was hoping for a quick solution using gpt. i'm not a dev and the resources you sent are beyond my understanding. i'll have to give up on this and maybe pick it back up when i have more time

If the context menu item is greyed out for you, that means it's not available for that program group, which means it's not going to work by code. What is the use case of restoring all Explorer windows at the same time? And if you do so, how would you expect to focus them all, since only one window can have focus?

looks like if the explorer windows are all minimized, the "Restore all windows" button does work, but if they are just in the background of other applications or a mix of background+minimized, that option is greyed out... I don't need to focus on any specific window, I just want them all up simultaneously. from there I can make a selection which one to focus on

the use case: its less confusing for me to see all explorer windows as I have arranged them. i usually have multiple projects with same folder structures and same folder names. I reference folders form other projects and get confused about which subfolder i'm in.. the paths to these subfolders are long, so the folder identifying the project is hidden in the address bar

I doubt the implementation you have with Shell.Application will ever work, leaving aside there is no .Focus() method on .Document. What you can do is call native functions to restore minimized windows, this solution should always work however the implementation is much harder since you're calling low level function with C# implementation.
Basically what the code below is doing is enumerating all windows with EnumWindows function where the window handle belongs to the specified Process Id passed as argument, with (Get-Process explorer).Id in this case, then minimizes, restores and activates the window.
Normally, minimizing the window shouldn't be required however from OP's feedback and after testing, it seems that if a different window is overlapping the explorer window simply activating / bring to front doesn't work consistently (also a tiny delay between minimizing and restoring seem to be required).
Add-Type @'
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Threading;

public static class Native
{
    private const int SW_SHOWDEFAULT = 10;
    private const int SW_MINIMIZE = 6;
    private const int SW_SHOW = 5;
    private delegate bool EnumWindowsProc(IntPtr hWnd, int lParam);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern bool EnumWindows(
        EnumWindowsProc enumFunc, int lParam);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern uint GetWindowThreadProcessId(
        IntPtr hWnd, out uint lpdwProcessId);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern bool IsWindowVisible(IntPtr hWnd);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    private static extern int GetWindowTextLength(IntPtr hWnd);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr GetShellWindow();

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    private static extern int GetWindowText(
        IntPtr hWnd, char[] lpString, int nMaxCount);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    internal static extern bool ShowWindowAsync(IntPtr windowHandle, int nCmdShow);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

    public static void RestoreWindowByProcessId(uint id)
    {
        IntPtr shellWindowhWnd = GetShellWindow();
        EnumWindows((IntPtr handle, int lParam) =>
        {
            if (handle == shellWindowhWnd)
            {
                return true;
            }

            if (!IsWindowVisible(handle))
            {
                return true;
            }

            uint processId;
            if (GetWindowThreadProcessId(handle, out processId) == 0)
            {
                return true;
            }

            if (processId != id)
            {
                return true;
            }

            int len;
            if ((len = GetWindowTextLength(handle)) == 0)
            {
                return true;
            }

            char[] buffer = new char[len];
            if (GetWindowText(handle, buffer, len + 1) == 0)
            {
                return true;
            }

            Console.WriteLine(string.Format(
                "Restoring window with Title: '{0}'",
                new string(buffer)));

            // minize the window first
            ShowWindowAsync(handle, SW_MINIMIZE);
            // add a tiny delay (after testing this is required for it to work consistently)
            Thread.Sleep(200);
            // restore window
            ShowWindowAsync(handle, SW_SHOWDEFAULT);
            ShowWindowAsync(handle, SW_SHOW);
            // activate window
            SetForegroundWindow(handle);
            return true;
        }, 0);
    }
}
'@

$process = (Get-Process explorer).Id
[Native]::RestoreWindowByProcessId($process)


thanks! i'll give this a try after asking IT to install visual studio or vs code on my work comp

there is no need for vscode but ofc nice to have if you're gonna write code. this impl as-is should run fine even in powershell 5.1 vanilla

@DEAGoblin i've added a few more details to help you understand what the code is doing

thanks for the notes! if I don't use visual studio, where can I find instructions on how to run this? will this be similar to the gpt instructions to create text.ps1 and run it through powershell?

@DEAGoblin thats right. you can even copy paste the code in a powershell prompt and it should work.

Any feedback on why this is down-voted so I can improve it? :)

i upvoted it, as with all other replies that are helpful to me. looks like @mklement0 posted an alternative script with comments to your script. thank you both for your help!

@DEAGoblin your question was also down-voted, no idea why

thanks for trying. this doesn't work if a window is up overlapping where the folders should populate. same issue with mklement0's script.

@DEAGoblin let me see if I understand what you're saying, so if a window that is not an explorer window (like a browser window for example) is overlapping one of the explorer windows then that explorer window doesn't come on top correct? or are you saying that all explorer windows are overlapping themselves in which case you need to re-arrange them so they don't overlap?

yes, you understood me correctly in the first sentence you write. if a window that is not an explorer window (like a browser window for example) is overlapping one of the explorer windows then that explorer window doesn't come on top. I'll try to tinker with your code to make it minimize all explorer windows before running the original script you have bc it looks like if an explorer window is minimized, it comes up correctly.

@DEAGoblin I think I have gotten it to work consistently however there has to be a tiny delay on each "restore window" operation: https://imgur.com/koDQaYc is that ok for you?

@DEAGoblin I've updated my answer using a different method that has been working consistently however it requires to 1. minimize the window before restoring it and 2. a tiny 200ms delay between minimizing and restoring

thanks for your efforts. for some reason every time there is only one explorer window that doesn't get pulled up. i'm using a work computer so maybe powershell has some limitations built into it for security reasons. this could be causing the difference on my end.


A solution is possible, however:

It is intrinsically slow, due to the nontrivial startup cost of powershell.exe, the Windows PowerShell CLI.

It is further slowed down by the need to use P/Invoke calls to the WinAPI from PowerShell, which entails on-demand compilation of C# code via Add-Type.


Specifically, you need to call the ShowWindow WinAPI function with SW_RESTORE in order to restore a minimized window to its original size, which the Shell.Application COM object doesn't do for you when you set a window's .Visible property to $true (it activates the window, but if it happens to be minimized, it is its taskbar icon that is activated).
While an all-P/Invoke solution as shown in Santiago's answer is possible, it may be easier to restrict the P/Invoke solution to the ShowWindow call, which allows you to stick with your original approach (as noted, $_.Document has no Focus() method, but you can use $_.HWND to pass the window handle to the P/Invoke call):
# Define a helper type that uses P/Invoke to call the ShowWindow WinAPI function, via custom wrapper method RestoreWindow.
# Note: 
#  * This incurs a once-per-session compilation performance penalty.
#  * Since you're calling via powershell.exe, you incur it every time.
$winApiHelperType = Add-Type -PassThru -NameSpace N$PID -Name WinHelper -MemberDefinition @'
  [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError=true)]
  static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);
  public static void RestoreWindow(IntPtr hWnd) { ShowWindow(hWnd, 9 /* SW_RESTORE */); }
'@ 

# Now try your original approach, but make sure that each window is
# restored (neither minimized nor maximized) via the P/Invoke call first.
$shell = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application
$shell.Windows() |
  ForEach-Object {
    if ($_.Name -eq "File Explorer") {
      # First, ensure that the window isn't minimized (or maximized).
      $winApiHelperType::RestoreWindow($_.HWND)
      # Then make it visible, i.e. activate it.
      $_.Visible = $true
    }
  }

Note:

The ShowWindow call with SW_RESTORE should normally also activate the targeted window, but seemingly doesn't in practice; thus, $_.Visible = $true is also needed for activation.

The solution by default only works if PowerShell is the foreground application, because Windows will otherwise prevent programmatic activation of other windows (and will flash their taskbar button instead) - this condition should be met if you invoke the script via a shortcut file, possibly via a shortcut key.

In cases where the condition is not met, this answer offers a solution.




thanks for your solution and notes. your script pulled up all explorer windows - both minimized and ones in background. Santiago's script was not able to pull up minimized windows.

seems like this doesn't work if another window is up and overlapping the folders

@DEAGoblin: Please see the last two bullet points I've just added to the answer; they explain under what circumstances the activation won't work, though I would expect it to work in your scenario. However, I may be misunderstanding your comment: what other window?

if a window that is not an explorer window (like a browser window for example) is overlapping one of the explorer windows then that explorer window doesn't come to the foreground. i will look for a way to minimize all explorer windows before running the script to bring all explorer windows back to foreground. thanks for your input

That is curious, @DEAGoblin: on my Microsoft Windows 11 Pro machine (ARM 64-bit Processor; Version 22H2, OS Build: 22621.4169) I don't see this symptom.
